# i move one domain to another domain getting double slash error

Tags: url

domain url 
i move magento website http://knathangee.com/doctor to http://jomedhealthcare.com//doctor/ getting "// 404 error" what is the issue sir.

I done this perfectly

Sql all link change perfectly

100% correct file uploading

Comment: view this link:-http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-move-your-website-from-one-domain-to-another.html#gref

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below mentioned code in your root .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```